# How to do parallel processing/multi threaded processing to call REST endpoints in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, rest

I have to achieve parallel process to make a call to 4 Micro service call at a time. Where I have an input of 16 where 4 process should consumed per microservice.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    if (m == i) {
        LOGGER.info("Inside If condition");
        String jsonMes1 = jsonArr.get(i).toString();
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8086/myService");

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(jsonMessage.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            LOGGER.info(" FAILED ");
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("  SUCESSFULLY PROCESSED ");
        }
        n = m;
        n++;
    } else if (n == i) {
        //Same process in different port
        o = n;
        o++;
    } else if (o == i) {
        //Same process in different port
        p = o;
        p++;
    } else if (p == i) {
        //Same process in different port
        m = p;
        m++;
    }
```

Same repetitive code all the 3 more else if conditions running in different port . But the problem once if the request from first is completed and then second is processing but I need to make in it parallel way. I just need to process it parallely where I am iterating the objects from JSON array. Please suggest how to achieve this in a parallel manner

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: It is processsing synchronously but I need to proceed asynchrnously t process 4 process to finish the process for 16 times

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to continue synchronously after the rest calls: Factor your variable parts out and put it in a list and then use parallel streams, e.g.:

```
Arrays.asList("port1", "port2", "port3").parallelStream()
   .forEach(port -> performRestCall(port));
```

Alternatively you could also use `ForkJoinPool`.

P.S. in the spirit of clean coding, avoid using variables like n, m, n, p.

Comment: Can you suggest how I can process multiprocessing in asynchronous way

Comment: You don't want to wait for the rest calls to return and continue execution? In other words, you only want to spawn worker threads in a fire and forget manner?